# Will MySQL return the latest info on API?

Tags: php, mysql, api

I am building an API for the website I created using PHP and MySQL. The API will be used primarily for a mobile app. That app will send a request to the API endpoint, which will reply with a response, so the mobile can parse it.

Users can login on their account via the website/mobile and do some actions like post offers, delete offers, update offers and browse other user's offers.

Now I am wondering, if things run on the same time will the database be able to return the latest data/information to the API request? I run across the `MySQL push` but didn't understand if this address my question.

I am pretty lost, so please be easy on my question. Maybe the quality of my question is below the average, it came up with this because of my limited knowledge.

Comment: Shouldn't the API be requesting from your system rather than the other way round?

Comment: What do you mean by "run on the same time" ? Are you talking about connections? Traffic? Data hanlding ?

Comment: That depends on many many many little things. Your application and database design, your API structure and hosting environment, the traffic that you expect to have. You can always create functions to limit the requests each client (mobile) makes to the API and reset when necessary. Keep the above in mind and save your self thinking about "same time" requests. It ll be fine.

Comment: @mallix - What is my gain when I reset the connection of the user from the API?

Comment: The database and API will return the latest data it has. If you are using InnoDB as the engine for mysql, your table will be row level locked on updates/inserts and deletes, if you use MyIsam it will be table level locked on updates/inserts and deletes. Apart from these things, the API should return latest data if you do not cache the output.

Comment: For example, you can control how many requests can a mobile client make per day for scaling your application accordingly. I would recommend also to save stats like elapsed time for each request, memory usage and total queries executed. Control your API usage till you are 100% sure it works and scale. Last but not least. Use authentication and SSL.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. Really appreciated it.